# How to divide image into blocks and find pixels colors

Tags: python, image-processing

I want to divide RGB image into blocks 8x8 = 64 (pixels in block) and extract pixels colors from block. I have divided image into blocks 8x8:

```
w, h = img.size # width, height of image
bw, bh = 8, 8 # block size
img = Image.open('anyimage.JPG')

img = np.array(img)

sz = img.itemsize
shape = (h-bh+1, w-bw+1, bh, bw
strides = (w*sz, sz, w*sz, sz) 
blocks = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(img, shape=shape, strides=strides)

print blocks[1,1]
```

I get this values in block:

```
[[169 185 147 170 186 149 170 187]
 [139 161 122 140 162 122 140 162]
 [131 135 113 131 135 118 135 142]
 [170 186 147 170 186 147 170 188]
 [142 164 124 142 164 122 140 162]
 [136 138 113 137 141 114 138 142]
 [174 191 148 174 191 147 173 190]
 [142 164 126 144 166 125 143 165]]
```

How to extract all pixels colors from block?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
pixels = img.load()

all_pixels = []
for x in range(block_width): #put your block width size
    for y in range(block_height): #your block heigh size
        cpixel = pixels[x, y] #reading elements from pixel on location (x,y)
        all_pixels.append(cpixel)
```

That appends every pixel to the all_pixel, in form of a tupple. For example

```
(111, 222, 255) #R-G-B
```

Comment: Thanks for respond. I had tried img.getdata() but it will return whole image pixels colors I need specific block pixels colors.

Comment: I am sorry but I am little confused by your objective. Can you provide some expected result?

Comment: Thanks, dpw for help. I want to divide image into blocks 8pixels x 8pixels = 64 pixels in one block, I have done it already with code I have posted before. From each block I want to list pixels colors in RGB (112, 231, 222) and convert it to luminance to get pixels colors intensity I do it in this way - (.299 * red) + (.587 * green) + (.114 * blue), when I have colors intensity from each block I want to find brightest block. But at the moment after I divide image to blocks I only get in blocks pixels coordinations, how to get pixels colors? I hope my question is clearer sorry for my english.